# Trying to understand meaning of 'alias | some-command" syntax

Tags: bash, alias

What does the piping of `alias` command mean here ?

```
$ alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

Comment: Pipe syntax feeds the stdout of the thing on the left to the stdin of the thing on the right. If you want to know what the stdout of `alias` is when run with no arguments, you can just try doing that: Run `alias`, and see what shows up on your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is a (nonportable) hack to let GNU `which` try to behave more like `type`.

The bash builtin tool for displaying not just external command locations but also aliases, functions, etc. is called `type`. When called with an alias (or a shell function), it will emit its definition:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

Because `which` is an external command, it has no way of knowing about aliases... *unless* they're fed to it on stdin:

```
$ alias                             # we have some aliases defined...
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias some-other-alias='whatever'
$ which ls                          # but which doesn't know about them...
/usr/bin/ls
$ alias | which --read-alias ls     # *unless* we feed the definitions to it via stdin
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    /usr/bin/ls
```

As you can see above, `which --read-alias` searches its stdin (assumed to be a list of aliases) for an alias definition that appears to match the command in question, and emits that on its output. It gets those definitions from the output of the shell-builtin `alias` command, which emits them when called with no arguments.

**This is still inferior, and you should use `type` instead whenever you know your shell to be bash.** Unlike `which`, `type` knows about shell functions; it knows about cached PATH lookups; it is guaranteed to be available everywhere bash is installed (unlike GNU `which`, which is unavailable by default on platforms which have non-GNU userland tools such as MacOS or FreeBSD); and it can do everything internal to the shell, without needing to spawn any external software.

Comment: For a very detailed write up on problems with `which` and what to do about it in most situations people can see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) on the U&L site